# format when column has specific name,

Tags: php

the roblem is where there is the punch commentator
i need when the column has INTER name or OUTER name to format the content of the $cell
with $cell=number_format($cell,2,',','.')
i'm just starting using php so don be too specific thanks

```
<?php  
  // printing table rows  
  $rigapadi = 1 ;  
  while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))  
  {  
      echo "<tr>";  
      $rigapadi=$rigapadi+1;    
      // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element    
      // of $row to $cell variable    
      foreach($row as $cell)    
         if ($rigapadi % 2 == 0) {    
             # if column name = 'INTER' or 'OUTER' $cell = number_format($cell, 2, ',', '.');  
             echo "<td align=\"center\">$cell</td>";  
          } else {  
             echo "<td bgcolor=\"#E9EEF5\" align=\"center\">$cell</td>";  
          }   
       echo "</tr>\n";  
    }  
    mysql_free_result($result);  
    echo "</table>";  
    echo "<p/>";   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The mysql_ are obsoltes. You must not use them. And please indent your code properly when you ask for help.

```
<?php
$rigapadi = 1;  
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {  
  echo '<tr>';
  $rigapadi++; 
  foreach($row as $name => $cell) {
    if($rigapadi % 2 === 0) {
      if($name === 'INTER' || $name === 'OUTER') {
        echo '<td align="center">' . number_format($cell, 2, ',', '.') . '</td>';
      } else {
        echo '<td align="center">' . $cell . '</td>';
      }
    } else {  
      echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#E9EEF5">' . $cell . '</td>';
    }
  }
  echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Note that I use fetch_assoc to get the $name.

PS: `<p/>` does not exists and align and bgcolor and not valids but acceptable if this is a HTML code for an e-mail.